# Layers from GRASS db won't load in QGIS 2.18.4 desktop

Tags: qgis, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin

I have been learning QGIS online but now I am stuck at a module. I am supposed to launch a project that includes GRASS vector and point layers. However, when I do so I always receive the 'Handle bad layers box'. When I use the browser panel and navigate to the the layers, they appear with red 'X' icons.

The same thing happens with the QGIS Alaska GRASS demo. I have GRASS 7 plugin enabled.

Is there something I am missing?

[image]